# Image with border-radius and :hover bug in Safari

Tags: html, css

When hovering over an image with border-radius, the style is set even when the cursor is outside the clipped image (inside the square containing the image).

This happens in Safari; it works correctly in Firefox and Chrome. Is there any way to fix it using CSS?

```css
.imagen {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.imagen:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Vado_l_ammazzo_e_torno-George_Hilton.jpg" class="imagen" />
```

Comment: no it's not, what browser version are you using? (on my chrome it's fine)

Comment: It works fine also in my Chrome

Comment: It works fine also in my Chrome

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's working because here not outside container of image.

Comment: Works on Chrome, does not work on Safari. Might want to change the question since others have said it works on Chrome too

Comment: @Hanif what container? there is no container involved, only an img

Comment: Just add wraper div outside image, set it's size and border radius, and add ` overflow: hidden; `

Comment: Yes you are right and it works in Chrome, sorry, doesn’t work in Safari. I was confused because adding a wrapping <a> to the image you can click on the whole rectangle. Is there any way to confine the link to the circle? (and of course is a double problem, because anything that would work on Chrome or FF wouldn’t work on Safari.

Comment: @DavidDeprost - Just a note: when making edits based on the comments on the question, please make a note of that in the edit summary. We can't see the comments when reviewing edits and it honestly looked like you were changing the meaning of the question before I double checked the post itself.

Comment: @BSMP Sure, I'll remember that next time.

Answer (score 2):

The best cross-platform solution is probably to use the CSS `url()` function with the `background` property:

```css
#image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Vado_l_ammazzo_e_torno-George_Hilton.jpg') 0px 0px/contain;
}

#image:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id='image'></div>
```

Comment: But then you have to move the image src definition to the CSS, which can be dynamic.

Comment: You can always write it to CSS from JS with e.g. `element.style.setProperty('background', value)`.

Comment: But what if the style is shared with several images?

Comment: If you're using a modern JS framework/library like React, you can turn it into a component that takes the image url as input. Otherwise, I'd probably isolate the background property in classnames specifying each individual image.